# Output json to php (frontend)

Tags: php, json, api

Here is the output as its beeing displayed right now in my index file (on the wesbite)
So this is what i have right now
https://gyazo.com/e3b5efb2c0ac9c7225c5c322ae92b0e9

And i want to have that displayed more nicley ( perhaps in a table with header from and then text )

That is my problem, im usure of what i can google or search for. Get the data that is saved in my json file. And Display it nicley in my index.

Get some of the values from my .json file and display them in my index.

Here is my php code.

```
$outfile= 'result.json';
$url='https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=MYAPIKEY';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
if($json) {
    if(file_put_contents($outfile, $json, FILE_APPEND)) {
        echo "Saved JSON fetched from “{$url}” as “{$outfile}”.";
    }
    else {
        echo "Unable to save JSON to “{$outfile}”.";
    }
}
else {
    echo "Unable to fetch JSON from “{$url}”.";
}

$option = $_GET['option'];
```

And here its how i's getting displayed in my .json file.

```
{"status":"ok","totalResults":20,"articles":[{"source":{"id":"cnn","name":"CNN"},"author":"Matt McFarland","title":"Has Elon Musk lost control of his hype machine?","description":"For years, the entrepreneur controlled public opinion of Tesla. That's changing.","url":"https://money.cnn.com/2018/07/26/technology/elon-musk-tesla/index.html",
```

Comment: Use `json_decode($JSON_STRING, true)`

Comment: `file_put_contents($outfile, $json, FILE_APPEND)` <- You can't typically just **append** more JSON. This will most likely make your `result.json` file invalid

Comment: What is your question? It's totally unclear what you're asking

Comment: Output my json file to frontend.

Comment: What have you tried? Is `echo $json;` not enough?

Comment: Yes that does display it. It's just a cluster of information. Is there any way to have it formated nicley ?

Comment: @MewTwo for what purpose? JSON is a data transfer format. Why do you need to pretty-print it?

Comment: Well im unsure of how i would do that. I need to get the news that are displayed in my json file and output it to my test website. Thats where im strugelling.

Comment: Unsure of how you would do _"what"_? Please edit your question to describe what it is you're actually trying to do, what you've tried and what isn't working. Show what you expect to happen vs what is actually happening.

Comment: My englisch is not the best i will try and update the question as best as i can. ( Done )

Comment: I'll try to interpret what he means. Perhaps he just want to display the json text in proper format for debugging. But there are some tools like https://jsonformatter.org/ in which you should only copy and paste the json text to format it there.

Comment: Execute Ajax request and you'll be able see JSON structure in pretty format in browser. E.g. in Chrome: F12 -> Network -> XHR -> your request -> preview

Answer (score 0):

You might have invalid json response. verify first whether do you have valid json. May be copy your response and check it in some validator website like [www.jsonlnt.com](https://jsonlint.com/)
if json is fine then PHP function json_decode($you_json_string_php_variable); will work fine.

Comment: Hi, the json file ist nor right. What can i do to fix it ? Isn't the output determined by the website im getting the Information from ?

Comment: Yes, either its the problem with receiving info or you might have string storing limit issue. First increase memory_limit in php.ini then make sure you are receiving complete info.